# could not deduce template argument if using typedef

Tags: c++

I have a problem with "Could not deduce template argument for T" error.

here is my class:

```
class PropertyAccess
{
public:
    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    struct SetterPointer { typedef void (TClass::*Type)(const TType&); };

    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    struct GetterPointer { typedef TType(TClass::*Type)(); };

    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    void Assign(
        TClass* object,
        typename SetterPointer<TClass, TType>::Type setter,
        typename GetterPointer<TClass, TType>::Type getter)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and here is how I use it:

```
class Test
{
public:
    int a;

    void Set(const int& v) { a = v; }
    int Get() { return a; }
};

void main
{
    Test test;
    PropertyAccess property;
    property.Assign(&test, &Test::Set, &Test::Get);  <---here is compile error
}
```

If i try to compile that code, I have error:

```
'void PropertyAccess::Assign(TClass *,PropertyAccess::SetterPointer<TClass,TType>::Type,PropertyAccess::GetterPointer<TClass,TType>::Type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'TType'
```

but if I change Assign method to:

```
void Assign(
        TClass* object,
        typename SetterPointer<TClass, TType>::Type setter,
        TType(TClass::*getter)())
    {
        ...
    }
```

then everything is alright. Why? I know that function type cannot be deduced if it has no args, but why it works in second case?

I use Visual Studio 2013 C++ compiller.

Comment: Interesting question. Part of the issue is that `SetterPointer` and `GetterPointer` are trying to be metafunctions, but you aren't "calling" them with two arguments. If I add this overload, which calls the metafunction, it works:

    template <typename TClass, typename T1, typename T2>
    void Assign(
        TClass* object,
        T1 setter,
        T2 getter)
    {
         Assign<TClass, decltype((object->*getter)())>(object, setter, getter);
    }

That's saying "if I want to `Assign` with a class and two types, look up the result type of the getter and use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ cannot deduce the enclosing type from its nested type. It is an example of *non-deduced context*.

A simplest example would be something like

```
struct S { typedef int T; };

template <typename C> void foo(typename C::T i) {}

int main()  {
   int x = 0;
   foo(x); // ERROR: non-deduced context
}
```

or, closer to what you have in your code

```
template <typename X> struct S { typedef X T; };

template <typename X> void foo(typename S<X>::T i) {}

int main()  {
   int x = 0;
   foo(x); // ERROR: non-deduced context
}
```

The same thing happens in your case as well, in a slightly more convoluted form. For template method `Assign` it is not possible to deduce template parameters `TClass` and `TType` through a function parameter like `typename SetterPointer<TClass, TType>::Type setter`. In your case template parameter `TClass` is deducible from the first argument of `Assign`, but `TType` is not deducible from any argument. Hence the error.

When you change declaration of the last parametr of `Assign` to `TType(TClass::*getter)()` you immediately make the context deducible, i.e. the compiler uses the getter argument as an opportunity to deduce `TType`.

In C++11 you can use alias templates to achieve the same `typedef` effect and still keep the context deducible

```
class PropertyAccess
{
public:
    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    using SetterPointer = void (TClass::*)(const TType&);

    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    using GetterPointer = TType(TClass::*)();

    template <typename TClass, typename TType>
    void Assign(
        TClass* object,
        SetterPointer<TClass, TType> setter,
        GetterPointer<TClass, TType> getter)
    {
       ... 
    }
};
```

Comment: very comprehensive answer, thank you. One thing I still don't understand: why it works correctly for setter? Please notice that I had to change only getter definition to make this code compile correctly.

Comment: @majakthecoder: It didn't really "work" for setter. Again, what the compiler has to do is to deduce two template parameters of `Assign`: parameter `TClass` and parameter `TType`. The compiler inspect the first argument of `Assign` (`object`) and that immediately allows it to deduce that `TClass == Test`. So, `TClass` parameter is now taken care of. The compiler proceeds to the second argument of `Assign` - `setter` - and sees that it is useless, since the context is non-deducible. The compiler simply skips it.

Comment: The compiler then proceeds to the third argument `TType(TClass::*getter)()` and deduces from it that `TClass == Test` (consistent with previous deduction) and that `TType == int`. All parameters are looked through now. All template arguments are deduced and deduced consistently. And thus the code compiles.

Comment: So, non-deduced context is not an error. Arguments in non-deduced contexts are simply ignored by the deduction algorithm. If all of your template parameters will get deduced by other means (through other function arguments), then you are still good. But if you end up with a template parameter that cannot be deduced from *any* of the function arguments, the code will fail to compile.

Comment: So is there any possibility to define "nice looking" typedefs for that pointers? Or maybe I have obsession with code form.

Comment: @majakthecoder: You can use "template typedef" (aka alias template) feature of C++11. `template <typename TClass, typename TType> using SetterPointer = void (TClass::*)(const TType&);`

Comment: See here: https://ideone.com/ma7MPf . It works for me in VS 2013 as well. See the extra example in my answer above.